# load-grunt-config not found task to launch

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm using load-grunt-config plugin to split my gruntfile. Here is my Grunfile.js :

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

   var path = require('path');

   // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
   require('time-grunt')(grunt);

   var options = {
      configPath: path.join(process.cwd(), 'Grunt')
   };

   require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, options);

   grunt.registerTask('checkCode', ['tslint']);
};
```

I got a folder named 'Grunt' and a file named tslint.js.

Everytime i use : `grunt checkCode` in my CLI i got the following error :

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
ReferenceError: grunt is not defined
Warning: Task "checkCode" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

I also try aliases file but this not work too.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem. Here is my tslink.js :

```
module.exports = {
    tslint: {
        options: {
             configuration: grunt.file.readJSON("tslint.json")
         },
         files: {
             src: ['**/*.ts']
         }
    }
};
```

This line don't work : `grunt.file.readJSON`. So i change my file and that's work perfectly :

```
module.exports = function (grunt, options) {
   return {
    tslint: {
        options: {
             configuration: grunt.file.readJSON("tslint.json")
         },
         files: {
             src: ['**/*.ts']
         }
      }
 }
  };
```